# SQL Join - Show data if a joined table doesn't hold any data

Tags: sql, join

I have a query that joins 3 tables together.
One is a SPAAPPOINTMENTS table - (Spa appointments with price charged in)
The second is SPAAPTADDONS - Addons for the appointments (Nibbles etc), Links between apts and rst
The third is RSTCATALOG table  - Where the addon price is located.

The query:

```
SELECT        SPAAPPOINTMENTS.APTID, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.SERVICECODE, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.LOCATIONCODE, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.STAFFCODE, 
                         SPAAPPOINTMENTS.BLOCKSTARTTIME, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.BLOCKENDTIME, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.I_RECID, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.S_STAYID, 
                         SPAAPPOINTMENTS.STATUSCODE, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.BLOCKEDTIME, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.GRATUITY, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.TEMPHOLDID, 
                         SPAAPPOINTMENTS.LASTCHGID, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.CANCELID, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.ITEMNO, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.COMMENTS, 
                         SPAAPPOINTMENTS.OFFSITELOCATION, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.PRICE, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.PRIORITY, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.SPAPKGCODE, 
                         SPAAPPOINTMENTS.ENFORCEGENDER, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.NEWSTATUS, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.RESTNO, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.DONOTMOVE, 
                         SPAAPPOINTMENTS.NOSHOW, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.OTHERGENDERREQUESTED, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.MADEBY, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.LINKCODE, 
                         SPAAPPOINTMENTS.CONFIRMED, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.CXLNUMBER, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.REQUEST, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.CUSTOMFIELD1, 
                         SPAAPPOINTMENTS.CUSTOMFIELD2, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.CUSTOMFIELD3, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.VIP, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.NOPREFERENCE, 
                         SPAAPPOINTMENTS.CUSTOMFIELD4, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.CUSTOMFIELD5, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.BOOKID, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.ARTSRESVNO, 
                         SPAAPPOINTMENTS.LMSCONFNO, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.ARTSGUESTID, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.CLUBNO, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.MULTIGRPID, 
                         SPAAPPOINTMENTS.MAINCONTACT, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.SPABKNAME, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.MULTIGRPAPPTXT, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.CONFCOMMENTS, 
                         SPAAPPOINTMENTS.MEMCODE, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.FAMILYMEMTYPE, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.COCOMMENTS, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.GRPMASTERID, 
                         SPAAPPOINTMENTS.GUESTTYPE, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.EXTUNIQUEID, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.SETUPTIME, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.BREAKDOWNTIME, 
                         SPAAPPOINTMENTS.PSBASEPRICE, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.PSCODE, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.PSCALENDARADJPCT, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.PSDETAILADJ, 
                         SPAAPPOINTMENTS.PSPRICE, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.PSDETAILADJSOURCE, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.PSDETAILADJTYPE, SPAAPPOINTMENTS.PSPRICETYPE, 
                         RSTCATALOG.C_DPRICE
FROM  SPAAPPOINTMENTS 
  INNER JOIN SPAAPPTADDONS ON SPAAPPOINTMENTS.APTID = SPAAPPTADDONS.APTID 
  INNER JOIN RSTCATALOG ON SPAAPPTADDONS.ITEMNO = RSTCATALOG.C_ITEM
```

This returns all data from the appointments table AS LONG AS THEY HAD A ADDON to the Spa Appointment.

If they just had an appointment, and no Add on, it doesn't return the data.
For example, if i use the query and postfix it with: `WHERE (SPAAPPOINTMENTS.APTID = 626746)`

It doesn't show any data, but there is a line in spaappopintments but NOTHING in the addons table.

If I use anopther AptID, which HAS HAD AN ADDON, it shows the data and is output from the query.

How can I get to show the data if there is NO data in the SPAAPTADDONS table please anyone?

Comment: You are looking for an outer join. You should also add the tag for the DBMS you are using. Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you join tables together you specify a *left* and a *right* table. An `inner join` will produce a set where the join condition is true for both the left and right side.

What you want is to get a set that has all the data from the *left* table along with the matching data from the *right* side. This is a `left join`.

But, as you also want to get the pricing information for the addons you need to join the third table too. As we can assume that there is a one-to-one matching between the addons and the pricing table it looks like we could use an `inner join` here, but this won't work as the joins are performed in order, meaning that last join will use the result from the first join as its left side (and that set will have null values for the appointments without any addons) - if we try to do an `inner join` with the pricing table those rows would be excluded, so you need a `left join` here too.

In the end you want this:

```
FROM SPAAPPOINTMENTS 
LEFT JOIN SPAAPPTADDONS ON SPAAPPOINTMENTS.APTID = SPAAPPTADDONS.APTID 
LEFT JOIN RSTCATALOG    ON SPAAPPTADDONS.ITEMNO  = RSTCATALOG.C_ITEM
```

On a side note I would encourage you to use table aliases to make the query a bit shorter and more readable. Something like this:

```
FROM SPAAPPOINTMENTS    apt
LEFT JOIN SPAAPPTADDONS add ON apt.APTID  = add.APTID 
LEFT JOIN RSTCATALOG    rst ON add.ITEMNO = rst.C_ITEM
```

Comment: Thank you so much , i experimented with LEFT OUTER JOIN and got it working as follows: FROM            SPAAPPOINTMENTS  
                        
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         SPAAPPTADDONS ON SPAAPPOINTMENTS.APTID = SPAAPPTADDONS.APTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         RSTCATALOG ON SPAAPPTADDONS.ITEMNO = RSTCATALOG.C_ITEM

Comment: @MatthewLowe Happy if I could help. Please consider marking any of the answers as accepted if it helped solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change the below `INNER JOIN` line

```
INNER JOIN SPAAPPTADDONS ON SPAAPPOINTMENTS.APTID = SPAAPPTADDONS.APTID
INNER JOIN RSTCATALOG ON SPAAPPTADDONS.ITEMNO = RSTCATALOG.C_ITEM
```

To an `LEFT OUTER JOIN` like

```
LEFT JOIN SPAAPPTADDONS ON SPAAPPOINTMENTS.APTID = SPAAPPTADDONS.APTID
LEFT JOIN RSTCATALOG ON SPAAPPTADDONS.ITEMNO = RSTCATALOG.C_ITEM
```

Comment: Note that unless the join to RSTCATALOG is changed to a left join too, the query would still exclude rows from SPAAPPOINTMENTS.

Comment: @jpw, may be my answer interpretation is confusing but I meant the same. I was pointing OP to convert the joins to outer joins. let me edit to clear this.

Comment: Yeah I thought that was what you meant, I just felt that it needed to be clarified :)

Comment: Thank you so much , i experimented with LEFT OUTER JOIN and got it working  as follows: FROM            SPAAPPOINTMENTS  
                        
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         SPAAPPTADDONS ON SPAAPPOINTMENTS.APTID = SPAAPPTADDONS.APTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         RSTCATALOG ON SPAAPPTADDONS.ITEMNO = RSTCATALOG.C_ITEM

Comment: @MatthewLowe, consider accepting the answer if it helped by clicking the check button.

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM  SPAAPPOINTMENTS 
LEFT JOIN SPAAPPTADDONS ON SPAAPPOINTMENTS.APTID = SPAAPPTADDONS.APTID 
LEFT JOIN RSTCATALOG ON SPAAPPTADDONS.ITEMNO = RSTCATALOG.C_ITEM
```

let all data from SPAAPPOINTMENTS to be in the result.

Comment: Thanks for your input , i used the following: FROM            SPAAPPOINTMENTS  
                        
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         SPAAPPTADDONS ON SPAAPPOINTMENTS.APTID = SPAAPPTADDONS.APTID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         RSTCATALOG ON SPAAPPTADDONS.ITEMNO = RSTCATALOG.C_ITEM